# unable to point out exact location via lat long

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have created a map to pin point the exact location for the customer's provided address. I am getting lat long for the address but it is not pointing out with a map marker on the map I do not know why it is not pointing out can anyone help me out pleasen here is my code

```
<?php
    $addresse    = $_POST['address'];
    $prepAddr    = str_replace(' ','+',$addresse);
    $geocode     = file_get_contents('https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$prepAddr.'&sensor=false');
    $output      = json_decode($geocode);
    $latitude    = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
    $longitude   = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
?>

<div id="map" style="width:400px;height:400px;"></div>

<script>
function unick() {
var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $latitude; ?>, <?php echo $longitude; ?>),
    zoom: 10,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.satellite
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
}
</script>
```

Comment: what does browser console says?

Comment: console is clear cordinates are coming but not pointing it out like a pin point come along is not showing to know that yes there is the location the city is coming out correctly but not pointing it out make sense ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add a marker to the map, like this:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);    
var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $latitude; ?>, <?php echo $longitude; ?>);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    map: map,
    title: 'You are here'
    label: 'You are here'
});
```

**Edit:** added title and label properties. For more information, see the [Google Maps API Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions)

Comment: VM4253:8 Uncaught ReferenceError: mapOptions is not defined

Comment: great it worked for me but is there a posibility to show the label i mean text like your location etc?

Comment: I have edited my post with information about labels. Please read the docs. :-)

Comment: acceped sorry for late accepting I was playing with it :-)